# Disable all inputs with the same array name

Tags: jquery, html, input

Is it possible using jQuery css like selectors?

```
<input type="text" name="user[name]" />
<input type="text" name="user[age]" />
<input type="text" name="user[height]" />
```

I was thinking of something like

```
$('[name="user"]´).prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the 'attribute starts with' selector to achieve what you require:

```js
$('[name^="user"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="user[name]" />
<input type="text" name="user[age]" />
<input type="text" name="user[height]" />
```

Note the `^=` operator. More info in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Perfect, just what i need (y)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with the `^=` operator

```js
$('input[name^="user"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="user[name]" />
<input type="text" name="user[age]" />
<input type="text" name="user[height]" />
```

P.S. You have a typo in `$('[name="user"]´)`, at the end after `]` `´` should be `'`